# Brushes in Illustrator are all round

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have ran into one of the most aggravating problems. I am working in Illustrator CC on a Surface Pro, mostly using 'Touch' mode. For some reason, all of my brush strokes have rounded edges.

[image: Screenshot of what I mean]

What I have tried..
1. Use a different brush
2. Create a new brush

I then contacted Adobe Customer Care for help and they reccomended...
1. Reseting Illustrator preferences
2. And going to View>Preview on CPU

All of which did nothing.

**How do I make the ends of my stroke pointed instead of round?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must create an **Art Brush** with the shape and end type you want:

[image: Brush1]

[image]

Shape and end types examples:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using a calligraphy brush. Are you aware of that?

Instead choose the Artistic_Ink Brush called "Tapered Stroke". It's available in the Brush panel drop down menu, under Open Brush Library > Artistic

Also set the "Variable Width Profile 1"

[image]